# passenger 3 standalone rvm rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, rvm

I have a rails app I am trying to run under passenger 3 standalone:

passenger start -a 127.0.0.1 -p 3001 -d

Ive installed this with rvm

cd myapp

rvm use 1.9.2

gem install passenger --pre

I want to set environment variables for my app but can't figure out how and where to set them.  I just need to source my .profile which has all my environment variables.  How do I do it?

passenger 3:
ruby 1.9.2
rails 3
rvm head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start passenger with variables like this:

```
VARONE=value VARTWO=value passenger start -a 127.0.0.1 -p 3001 -d
```

Answer (score 1):

$ passenger start --help
Usage: passenger start [directory] [options]
Starts Phusion Passenger Standalone and serve one or more Ruby web applications.

Options:
    ...
    -e, --environment ENV            Framework environment (default:
                                     development)
    ...